# Having hard time getting conditional code regarding permissions to work in an Orchard view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I am trying to do something like this in my view:

```
@if (AuthorizedFor(MyNameSpace.Security.Permissions.Client))
{
    <p>This is the Client view</p>
}
else if (AuthorizedFor(MyNameSpace.Security.Permissions.Manager))
{
    <p>This is the Manager view</p>
}
```

My permissions include Manager and Client, with Client having `ImpliedBy = new[] { Manager }`. Manager is sterotyped to Admin role, and Client to the Contributor role.

My expectation is that if the Manager is logged in they will only see the Manager view. However, because Manager has Client rights, the logic displays the first only (Client view). If I make both an `if` statement, then both pop up. When logged in as a Client I only see the Client view.

This makes sense, however, is it possible to code around that without having to do anything major? I am using my own front-end not tied to parts, so the ContentPermission module is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
@if (AuthorizedFor(MyNameSpace.Security.Permissions.Client))
{
    if (AuthorizedFor(MyNameSpace.Security.Permissions.Manager) {
        <p>This is the Manager view</p>
    } else {
        <p>This is the Client view</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this work if there were 3 or more permissions each cascading from the last (Manager > Supervisor > Staff > Client)? Or would it change up much?

Comment: You would need another level per permission, http://pastebin.com/umRV7i4R but for too many levels it is not an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Do as you did, but start with the most powerful role:

```
@if (AuthorizedFor(MyNameSpace.Security.Permissions.Manager))
{
    <p>This is the Manager view</p>
}
else if (AuthorizedFor(MyNameSpace.Security.Permissions.Client))
{
    <p>This is the Client view</p>
}
```

You can extend this to more roles, as long as it comes to the most powerful role first a user will always be shown the most powerful options that their role membership allows.